# Update Solana CLI

Tags: solana-cli

The current version of Solana CLI on my mac is

`solana-cli 1.9.29 (src:0c54340a; feat:462418899)`

When I run update, it does not update to current version `1.11.0`. Which command should I run to properly update?

Answer (score 4):

`solana-install update`

Otherwise I would just uninstall and reinstall if the update command doesn't work.